# Regression on Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, homework, statistics, pandas, clustering

I am working on the following assignment and I am a bit lost:

> Build a regression model that will predict the rating score of each
>   product based on attributes which correspond to some very common words
>   used in the reviews (selection of how many words is left to you as a
>   decision). So, for each product you will have a long(ish) vector of
>   attributes based on how many times each word appears in reviews of
>   this product. Your target variable is the rating. You will be judged
>   on the process of building the model (regularization, subset
>   selection, validation set, etc.) and not so much on the accuracy of
>   the results.

This is what I currently have as code (I use `mord`'s API for the regression model since `Rating` is categorical):

```
# Create word matrix
bow = df.Review2.str.split().apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
rating = df['Rating']
df_rating = pd.DataFrame([rating])
df_rating = df_rating.transpose()
bow = bow.join(df_rating)

# Remove some columns and rows
bow = bow.loc[(bow['Rating'].notna()), ~(bow.sum(0) < 80)]

# Divide into train - validation - test
bow.fillna(0, inplace=True)
rating = bow['Rating']
bow = bow.drop('Rating', 1)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(bow, rating, test_size=0.4, random_state=0)

# Run regression
regr = m.OrdinalRidge()
regr.fit(x_train, y_train)
scores = cross_val_score(regr, bow, rating, cv=5, scoring='accuracy')
# scores -> array([0.75438596, 0.73684211, 0.66071429, 0.53571429, 0.60714286])
# avg_score -> Accuracy: 0.66 (+/- 0.16)
```

Could I have some constructive criticism on the above code please (regarding what I am missing from the posed task)?

---

This is what `bow` looks like:

[image]

If you need any other information just comment I will happily edit it in.

P.S: I've been working on this the past few days, this is my first regression model I code. I'll be honest, I didn't find it easy. So if someone could lend a helping hand I would be so ever grateful. Lastly, I want to be clear that I don't post to get a complete answer, code-wise (even if I would not say no to that). I am merely hoping in some guidance. My deadline approaches fast :P

Comment: The wording of the question feels like the code does not work as expected and you're asking about implementing missing features. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: No, I believe that the code works correctly but I am wondering if I "hit all the targets".